# how make a skip extension install from downloader or magento connect

Tags: magento-1, extensions, magento-connect, downloader

here what i want to do. i want to skip the installation if the module is already install from **magento connect** or **downloader** is this possible? i have module that are packaged with every extension that are causes the problem. What i want if that module is already installed then skip that module installation?

**Error: file already exist.**